# Why does the transition not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transition

I got a Section named "login" and a Section named "register".
When the opacity of them changes, I want to have a linear transition that take 0.3 seconds.

**CSS:**

```
#login{
opacity: 0;
transition:opacity 0.3s linear;}

#register{
opacity: 0;
display: none;
transition:opacity 0.3s linear;}
```

When you go on the Homepage [HERE](http://pixeld.bplaced.net/Workbench/) and click on "Query",
the opacity of `#login` changes to 1. That works fine with the transition!
When you click "oder registriere dich neu" below the Login-Form,
the Login-Section gets `opacity: 0` again - then get `display: none`.
That also works perfect with a transition.

**BUT** than the REGISTER-Section is put to `display: block` and then `opacity: 1` (after a `setTimeout` of 500 Milli-seconds.)
This don't have a transition! why?
When i click "Hast du schon einen Account?" again (to get back to the login),
the register Block will fade out with a transition perfecty again, and the login-form comes up **without** a transition again?

Here's the Javascript code for setting the opacities:

```
function changeSection(IDOut, IDIn)
{
    var IDOut = "#" + IDOut;
    var IDIn = "#" + IDIn;

    hideSection(IDOut);
    showSection(IDIn);
}

function hideSection(IDOut)
{
    $(IDOut).css({opacity: "0"});
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(IDOut).css({display: "none"});
    },500);
}

function showSection(IDIn)
{
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(IDIn).css({display: "block"});
        $(IDIn).css({opacity: "1"});
    },500);

}
```

IDOut is the Section, I want to Fade out (witch works perfect for login and register).

IDIn is the Section, I want to Fade in (witch DON'T WOKR for login and register)!

**Why does the transition not work for IDIn?**
Any Ideas?

Comment: Please, give us a jsfiddle so we can edit!

Comment: Anyway, you can try put `$(IDIn).css({display:'block'});` outside of setTimeout.

Comment: Also doesn't work outside of the setTimeout.
I try to put it on jsfiddle, wait a moment.

Comment: Sorry, i am new to jsfiddle and the whole site don't work up there.
Put i put the Link to the Site in the Question, you can see and edit the source-code with google-chrome and firefox i think!

Comment: I override `showSection` and it works though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transition does not work according to your code.

The IDIn originally has the `display` property as `none` and `opacity` as `0`.

According to the function `showSection`, you first wait for 500ms, and then set the `display` and `opacity` property **simultaneously** to what you want. **Concurrency** is the problem, because display and opacity are changed in one animation frame at the same time, but the browser has to choose one property to transit. And it choose `display`.

More technically, transition only works on elements that are visible and have dimension. The width and height must not be zero. So `display:none;` cancels out your transition.

So the solution is easy, just put `display` outside of your `setTimeout`. Make `display` changed first.

The benefit over native jQuery method `fadeIn` is that it utilizes css transition, which is more efficient than jQuery's underlying animation.

```
function showSection(IDIn)
{        
    $(IDIn).css({display: "block"});
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(IDIn).css({opacity: "1"});
    },500);

}
```

Comment: Anyway, using fadeIn is a lot more easier. So choose whatever you like ;)

Comment: Man, you are my hero for today. THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

You are using jQuery, you can do this alot simpler and let the jQuery handle it for you.

instead of your code for showSection and hideSection, use:

```
$('#yourselector').fadeIn(300);
```

to fade an element in with a time of 300 miliseconds, and:

```
$('#yourselector').fadeOut(300);
```

to hide it.

Comment: What does fadeOut and fadeIn exactly do? Does it just change the opacity?

Comment: fadeIn / fadeOut change opacity and display of the element so a display block opacity 1 element, will first have animate to opacity 0, then display none. this does everything you need.

Comment: I think that would also work, thanks! I decided for the solution @Herrington Darkholme.

Comment: His answer was the correct one so therefore you did the right thing, he actually explained how and what, gonna +1 his answer as he deserves it :)